# Angularjs/jQuery: Change table's width after ajax call finishes.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table whose default width is a certain value, say 80% of the parent div. The table is initially hidden using 'ng-if' until a certain ajax call is finished **as follows:**

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-if="!loading">
    <table id="table-stable">
        <thead>
            //columns
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in tableData">
                //rows
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**AngularJS Controller:**

```
$scope.loading = true;
someFactory.getData().then(function(data) {
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.tableData = data;
    //now need to write code to change table's width dependant on data.
})
```

As explained in the controller, depending on the data that is fetched from the factory, I need to change the width of the table.

The thing is that 2 columns of the table are not shown according to the values in the data fetched and so, if those columns are not shown then I need to shrink the table's width.

Currently, writing jQuery after the ajax call has finished isn't working. Code for the controller specified above:

```
$scope.loading = true;
    someFactory.getData().then(function(data) {
        $scope.loading = false;
        $scope.tableData = data;
        $('#table-stable').attr('width', '100px'); //not working.
    })
```

My guess is that the table hasn't been rendered completely? Well, I am shooting in the dark here. How do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change a variable indicating whether those columns should be shown based on the data, you can use `ng-class` and your element's classes will live-update.

For example, give yourself these CSS classes:

```
.wide-table {
    width: 80%;
}

.narrow-table {
     width: 100px;
}
```

And then in the view, something like:

```
<table id="table-stable" ng-class="{'narrow-table': columnsHidden, 'wide-table': !columnsHidden}">
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvuxq8nh/).

Update: Since you're using `ng-if`, you could potentially just use an expression inside a vanilla class attribute, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/jvuxq8nh/2/).

Answer (score 2):

> My guess is that the table hasn't been rendered completely?

You're right. Using `ng-if` would complicate the things, use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` instead. Also, jQuery is objectionable here, there are not so many scenarios when it is really useful with Angular. You can do

```
<div ng-show="!loading">
    <table id="table-stable" ng-style="lengthyTable && { width: '100px' }">
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out I was doing the jQuery wrong. Somebody pointed this out in the comments(deleted now though)

**Previous code:**

```
$('#table-stable').attr('width', '100px');
```

**Correct code:**

```
$('#table-stable').css('width', '100px');
```

Comment: Yes... exactly. Another thing you shouldn't do UI reponsibility to your controller. Better if do that trick inside the view ;)

Comment: The problem is not here, `attr` property works : [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xp2255r4/)

Comment: You shouldn't ever do any DOM manipulation in the controller anyway.  DOM manipulation should only be done in a directive.  The two answers you got from others, suggesting the use of ngStyle/ngClass are the right way to go.